# Maven: benefit of specifying dependencies's versions as properties for single module project

Tags: java, maven

On various projects I've been working on, I've seen diferent ways of specifying dependencies versions. On some projects, the package version is written on the same dependency declaration:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.extensions.validator.validation-modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-extval-property-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.7</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

On others, a property is used, as in:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.extensions.validator.validation-modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-extval-property-validation</artifactId>
        <version>${versions.extval}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

For multimodule projects, I can see a clear benefit in declaring versions on the parent pom to avoid duplication (and the potential confusion and errors that come with it), but on single module applications, would there be a benefit to use such a level of indirection?

What would be a best practice for this and why?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a version property you can override it on the command line whereas with a fixed version you cannot.

So you can recompile your project with a newer version just by specifying it on the command line.

```
mvn -Dversions.extval=2.0.8 clean package
```

Or something.

apart from that, mostly used on multi-projects, and although there you have the dependency management section as well for versions.

Comment: another reason is that if you have a lot of dependencies that relate to same library, you would have to duplicate the version string a lot. Say with Spring for instance it is reasonable to define the spring framework version in a property so it would be then shared with all dependencies and can be updated in just one location, even for a single artifact.

Comment: correct, sorry. Very obvious and I use it a lot, I just forgot to elaborate it :)

Comment: Thanks to you both, eis and Niels. That was helpful :)

I see now where I could use property versioning for dependencies. It wasn't a pressing question but it's one of those things that itch sometimes, now knowing what path to take for some issues.